# WFS-T in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, gis

My group is working with the GeoServer's GIS server, which provides the WFS service.

We are not sure how to make an HTTP POST request in Elips and send the following xml as part of the request:

```
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd http://www.openplans.org/topp http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=topp:tasmania_roads">
  <wfs:Insert>
    <topp:tasmania_roads>
      <topp:the_geom>
        <gml:MultiLineString srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#27354">
          <gml:lineStringMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
494475.71056415,5433016.8189323 494982.70115662,5435041.95096618
              </gml:coordinates>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:lineStringMember>
        </gml:MultiLineString>
      </topp:the_geom>
      <topp:TYPE>mytest</topp:TYPE>
    </topp:tasmania_roads>
  </wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the elips you are talking about

http://www.openplug.com/products/elips-studio

Then this seems to be more of an elips problem than a flex problem.

It seems that since Flash Player 5 there has been a relatively easy way to send XML via Post

http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary855.html

or are you stuck on how to make the XML. Does Elips have a special way of doing thing?

Comment: Thx for your answer. I have found out how this is done in the Flex framework and it works fine with a WFS server. The problem is in Elips Studio. It's the same code, but it doesn't work on the WFS server. But Elips is still in Beta.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending it by pidgeon?

Answer (score 0):

You should try recompiling your kernel and wire it up with "the new ipad" to get that magic feeling of Apple-power!